# iOS app hanging on splash screen - compatibility issues?

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, ios8

iOS 8, xcode 6.0.1, unity 4.54f1

Last night I updated my iPhone5 to iOS 8. It requested `xcode 6.0.1` which in turn requested to update Unity. I did everything that was asked and now after I build to my iPhone, the app gets stuck on the splash screen. I tried building to an iPad with iOS 7 and that did not work either.

They both get stuck after the log says `applicationDidBecomeActive()` and then `applicationWillResignActive()`. Exiting the app will say that `Thread0` has crashed and it will show me a method call that worked fine 2 days ago. Android still works perfectly fine.

My question is: are there compatibility issues between xcode/unity/ios8/all 3 at this point? What can I do about it?

Comment: If you suspect compatibility issues contact support and check the forums. If you want help with your code specifically you'd have to provide more details about the nature of the crash and code involved.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the problem was with a hackish plugin that was made to run a unity app in the background which no longer applies to the current version of xcode. Apologies for wasting your time.